# Purpose of QueryNotificationErrorsQueue in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

What is the functionality of QueryNotificationErrorsQueue in MS SQL Server?

As the only permission difference between SQLDependency and SQLNotificationRequest is of RECEIVE permission on  **QueryNotificationErrorsQueue**. SQLDependency require it and SQLNotificationRequest wont require.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the initiator side queue for query notifications. It is never physically used, messages enqueued into it (which could be only error responses from QN notification delivery attempts) are intercepted at enqueue time and get special treatment. Same happens for the other system queues: `EventNotificationErrorsQueue` and `ServiceBrokerQueue`. It is not possible for applications to ever receive messages from these three system queues.

Neither SqlDependecy nor SqlNotificationRequests should require RECEIVE permissions on the `QueryNotificationErrorsQueue`. Can you point out where did you read the information that SqlDependency requires it?

Comment: Thanks for reply following link will provide you the permission details required : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188311(SQL.100).aspx Secondly, i had tried it myself too when i revoked the rights of user from QueryNotificationErrorsQueue it through the exception.

Comment: There is no requirement for RECEIVE permission in order to subscribe and deliver Query Notifications. The fact that SqlDependency checks for it is a bug. But now, of course, by the fact that SqlDependency check for i, it has become a requirement for SqlDependency.